# Time complexity of boolean exist and hashtable in java

Tags: java, hashtable, time-complexity, java-io

I am using boolean exists to check if a file exist in the directory or not. I want to know the time complexity of this method, some part of code is here

```
 File fil = new File(StoreFolder + "\\"+FileData); 
    boolean exists = fil.exists(); 
    if (!exists)
    {

    //DO SOMETHING    
    }
    else
    {
    StoreVirus[(int)TotalVirusCount]=StoreFolder;
    TotalVirusCount++;
    System.out.println("path:" +StoreFolder +" "+FileData);
    }
```

also i am comparing two string arrays, for that i am using the following code ,i want the time complexity for this code also , please provide some help , thanks in advance

```
      Hashtable hash=new Hashtable();
      for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
      hash.put(plist[i], 0);
      }
      for(int j=0;j<totalup;j++){
          if(hash.containsKey(upd[j])){
          hash.put(upd[j], 1);
          }
          else{
          hash.put(upd[j],0);
          }
     Enumeration e=hash.keys();
     while(e.hasMoreElements()){
     String tr=(String) e.nextElement();
     if(hash.get(tr)!=0)
     {
     System.out.println(tr);
     jTextArea1.insert(tr +"\n", 0);
     }

                             }

      }
```

upd and plist are the string arrays.

Comment: `Hashtable` and `Enumeration`? No generics? How old is this code exactly? Is this Java 7? If yes, don't use `File`, use `Paths` and `Files`

Comment: @fge this is at least Java 1.4.2 or probably older. You can notice by reading `Hashtable` with no generics at all.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is well suited for SO

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza this may also be code copy/pasted from somewhere really old...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza If it was Java 1.4.2, he would instead be using `HashMap` and `Iterator`. Looks like Java 1.1 or 1.0 to me...

Comment: @gparyani probably not since I know *good Java 1.4.2 designers that used Hashtable and Vector since they need to store this data and handle it synchronized*.

Comment: @fge god bless us (and OP) that this code wasn't copied from anywhere.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Couldn't one use `Collections.synchronizedList` or `Collections.synchronizedMap` for the same purpose?

Comment: @gparyani note the usage of *italic* to stand out my sarcasm.

Comment: Why isn't this suited for SO? This is programming related.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, but still, one could wrap the collection in a synchronized decorator by using methods in the `Collections` classes.

Comment: @Blaine IMO this question can be answered by a CS student (no offense against your answer) so it doesn't show any effort from OP.

Comment: @gparyani I know that. Some people just don't understand the sarcasm =\...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Right, but just because it can be answered easily by someone, doesn't mean that it shouldn't be here. Not everyone has a CS degree :)

Comment: @Blaine I don't have a CS degree and I can answer this :P.

Comment: Lol... Well not everyone is as bright as you :P Time complexities, are, well, complex; or, they can be ;)

Comment: @Blaine this is covered in the basics of time complexity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity. No rocket science. And I'm not here to babble about how bright I could be, this question just shows that OP has done a zero effort to solve it.

Comment: Well, I can't argue with that.

Comment: @RSverma your problem is about calculating the time complexity of your algorithms. You have an answer, if it solves your curiosity/problem, then cool. Next time try to solve this by your own and if you can't post your question and explain what have you done to solve it.

Comment: @ALL sorry for every thing(for coping code ,question can be answer by any cs student,not a well suited question for SO) But the code is for the following purpose -i have 2 string arrays , i am storing running processes(on my system) in one list, and other processes name in another string array , i want the common processes in both the arrays,for that code is working fine with java 7 , if any one have algo that has the complexity less then o(n*n) , can also suggest, but please provide help regarding complexity of exist method and this hashtable code

Comment: You're post asked for the time complexity of the 2 algorithms, I've given that to you. If that isn't what you want, you should edit the question to accurately reflect what you are looking for.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza well , i searched for the complexity of exist method , and for hash table method,but didn't get sufficient help , if u can ,plz provide , rather discussing other things.

Comment: @RSverma the `exists` method can be assumed as O(1) since it depends on the OS that will map the path directly to the disk location. The second algorithm, it takes O(N^2) since you traverse all the elements of the array. For the record, most of Hash Table operations takes O(1).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the second algorithm has a nested loop, which increased the run time. At least that's how it appears with the brackets.

Comment: @Blaine comment updated, thanks. And it will be O(N^2) since the number of elements in `hash` is the same of `plist`. Still, by reading the code inside the `while` loop, it is a naive approach.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for your valuable help , but  i am not getting properly (due to new for java) so could you please provide more explanation for that(any  web site link )

Comment: @RSverma it's on the net. I just searched *hash table time complexity* and found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table. Note that `Hashtable` class in Java is an implementation of hash table data structure. Since you're using Java 7, you probably want to use `Map` backed by a `HashMap` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part has a run time of `O(1)` and the second has a run time of `O(n^2)`.

It should be noted that these run times are "worst case" run times.

On average, the run time of the second algorithm is going to be `O(n*k)`;

Comment: could u plz explain it how ?

Comment: Hash tables have a run time of O(1) because it makes 1 call directly to the element that your looking for because it has a key/value. For loops assume that you are going to have to iterate over each element to get the answer. When you nest loops your run time grows exponentially. This is something that you should really read up on.